# runtime error (SIGSEGV)

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   char arr[1000][80];
   char output[1000][80];
   int n,i,j;
   int num[1000];
   cin>>n;
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
    cin>>num[i];
      cin>>arr[i];
   }
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
      for(j=(num[i]-1);j<(strlen(arr[i])-1);j++)
      {
        arr[i][j]=arr[i][j+1];
      }
      arr[i][j]='\0';
      cout<<"\n"<<(i+1)<<" "<<arr[i];
   }
  return 0;
}
```

This is the code which while uploading on Spoj gives the above error. The same code runs fine on Borland C++.

Comment: I think it might be a typo for spoj (http://www.spoj.pl/), in which case it might be useful to post the challenge number. Reread instruction carefully, e.g do they say the length of input string will be at most 80 characters. As a hint: I think you can process and output right after inputting, no need for a large array.

Comment: I think for the represented code snippet it would be very good to use assertions not to get out of the range of arrays!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the input you pass to this program, the variable `n` may be more than 1000, `cin>>arr[i]` may read more than 80 characters, and if `num[i] <= 0 || num[i] >= 80` then you will index past the beginning or end of one of your strings. All of these problems exist because this code uses fixed-size arrays and doesn't do any bounds checking.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing inherently wrong as far as I can see at first glance. However a segfault is certainly very possible when providing inputs your code can't cope with.

There's nothing preventing from writing outside the boundaries of `arr` on input for example.

Is there a specific input for which this fails?

Comment: i dont know what the spoj team is giving input. In borland c++ version 5 its working fine.

Comment: It's only fine for certain inputs... add checks for all your inputs and it'll work fine too. this is not a compiler related problem

Answer (score 0):

The value of the variable `n` can be greater than the array bounds. That is why your code can give an  array index out of bounds exception, and consequently why it gives a runtime error (`SIGSEGV`).